# problem running start..run..wscript a.vbs a.bat

Tags: vbscript, windows-xp, batch-file, command-prompt

I have these 2 files  a.vbs and a.bat  each has only one line.

a.vbs

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

a.bat

```
copy c:\blah\y.y c:\
```

When it works, it runs a.bat quietly in the background, which does the file copy.

I can do start..run...a.vbs a.bat
That works. 
I can open a command prompt and do wscript a.vbs a.bat

But the thing that doesn't work, is this

start...run...wscript a.vbs a.bat

if I put an msgbox in a.vbs, it's clear that runs.
But it looks like a.bat doesn't run when using that method..

Howcome that form doesn't work?

Comment: Just wondering, why are you using a batch file instead of simply calling [`FileSystemObject.CopyFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf9e7w.aspx) from your VBScript script? (Or is this just a dummy example?)

Comment: a dummy or demonstration example.. so didn't have to be a copy in the batch file, could've been some other command. But asking why that method isn't working.

Comment: and I suppose one would be best off writing whatever was in the batch, in vbscript..  But i'm still curious about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When WScript.Arguments(0) is not a full path, a.bat needs to be in the current directory.

You can check the current directory with:

```
WScript.Echo WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory
```

If a.bat is always in the same folder as a.vbs, you can use a full path:

```
set fso=WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
thepath=fso.BuildPath(fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName),"a.bat")
WScript.Echo thepath
```

Comment: hmm, I think your general point has cottoned onto the general problem.. making sure I used absolute paths everywhere.  
wscript c:\blah\inv.vbs c:\blah\a.bat   
and absolute paths with the copy command within the bat..
very mundane..
nevertheless, I will try to isolate things further and add if I find anything.

Comment: well, I can't seem to reproduce the problem.. I had to rename the files at one point. I tried changing them to absolute paths, it seems to work now.. and when I change many of those paths back , it still works..
wscript c:\blah\inv.vbs a.bat     (as you  say, a.bat in the same dir - which I had infact)
and a.bat doesn't need absolute paths in the file copy. 
I don't know exactly what was going wrong. 
Why wscript with it didn't work but without did work. But, the problem was in the area you said..  and I see how the code you provided helps to see what's going on too.

Comment: I see that when not specifying a path to the vbs file, then, doing it with wscript, then it will find any vbs file in the path, whereas with wscript it only looks in %userprofile%.  But that wasn't the cause of the behaviour, since the vbs file was in a directory that wasn't in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a vbscript just to call a .bat?  `Start --> Run --> a.bat`

If you have to do it that way, do `Start --> Run --> cscript a.vbs a.bat`

Comment: That method , doing it within the vbs file, runs the bat or whatever command, in the background without opening up a command window. Infact, my question mentions that.